# How to change a javascript boolean from a html button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button onClick in the HTML side. I'm using a javascript function to do some actions. I need to change the value of a boolean using the HTML button. I have been looking at the forum but so far I didn't find something. Somebody can guide me here?

Thanks.

code:

> JS

```
var buttonClicked = false;

  window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  console.log(buttonClicked);
  document.getElementById('BtnGotit').addEventListener('onclick',function(){
    buttonClicked = true;
    console.log(buttonClicked);
  });
  });


 function desktopMove(e){

if(buttonClicked == true){
            var wH = $(window).height();
            var wW = $(window).width();
            var x = e.clientX;
            var y = e.clientY;
            if(x <= 20){
                //Left
                $pageTrigger = $('.pt-page-current').find('.right');
                    if($pageTrigger.length)
                        Animate($pageTrigger);
            }else if(x >= (wW - 50)){
                //Right
                $pageTrigger = $('.pt-page-current').find('.left');
                    if($pageTrigger.length)
                        Animate($pageTrigger);
            }else if(y <= 50){
                //Top
                $pageTrigger = $('.pt-page-current').find('.back');
                    if($pageTrigger.length)
                        Animate($pageTrigger);
            }else if(y >= (wH - 50)){
                //Bottom
                $pageTrigger = $('.pt-page-current').find('.next');
                    if($pageTrigger.length)
                        Animate($pageTrigger);
            }

        }
        }
```

> HTML

`>        <button2  onclick="function()" class = "BtnGotit" >Ok, GOT IT.</button2><`br>

Comment: Hard to say without providing your code.

Comment: They're going to down-vote you if you don't add some code fast.  And they won't be back to up-vote when you fix.  Please write your html code and your javascript code in your post.  (You write it where your question goes, but you just indent a few times, so that it will format it as code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to include your source code in the question because it helps us answer. You can add a code snippet with a demo of your code.

When the page loads, the button will be monitored for clicks. When clicked, the `buttonClicked` variable is set to `true`. `buttonClicked` value is initially `false`.

```js
var buttonClicked = false;

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  console.log(buttonClicked);
  document.getElementById('randoButton').addEventListener('click',function(){
    buttonClicked = true;
    console.log(buttonClicked);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="randoButton" value="Set the variable value">
```

Comment: Forgot the code. I edit the post above, I'm getting a  error in the java code, in this line:

  document.getElementById('randoButton').addEventListener('click',function(){

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of

Comment: @fullrusian is it properly nested in an onload event? If it runs prematurely, it won't work.

Comment: i not nested in an onload event, how can i  make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Change the "class" attribute on the button to "id". It should work. Also, remove the "onclick" attribute on the button. Since there is an event listener, you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *simple* example how to approach it:

```js
let bool = true

const changeValue = () => {
    bool = !bool
    console.log(bool)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeValue()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the simplest manner, this is a good start to toggle with one button.

```html
<input id="Z" value="0" type="range" max="1">
<button onclick="(Z.value<1)?Z.value++:Z.value--">Switch</button>
```

Note that it is inline javascript, this isn't the best to do for complex programs, see instead the usage of [EventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)!